# Allow rooms to opt-out of onebox previews

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, onebox

In the Ruby chat room, we've noticed that gist one-boxing has been fixed:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27523117#27523117

If you check our room's transcript, you'll see that a couple minutes before I deleted a message, which contained the same code from the gist. When sample code is more than a few lines, we ask others to post a gist of it instead. As Wayne, the room owner, says:

> I'm not so sure about that new feature. We use gists to avoid [pasting] code into the room.
>
> [*- Wayne Conrad*](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27523187#27523187)

This is just one example of obtrusive one-boxing in chat rooms. Others may think YouTube is obtrusive, especially while keeping chat SFW (relevance, not just content). While one-boxing, in general, is very useful, I can see how certain instances of it can be disruptive to a chat room's flow.

Room owners should be allowed to opt-out of *all* one-box previews. I understand that individual one-box opt-outs are unlikely, but I think this is an easy enough feature to implement. There would also be no need for a user to go out of their way to block elements or install a userscipt to "opt-out".

Comment: Some stuff gets one-boxed - others don't. Just don't post it so that it one-boxes maybe? Otherwise, this'll extend to images/SO posts/twitter/etc... requests per room (and chat isn't that finely grained)

Comment: What is one-box? The preview?

Comment: If you send a post consisting of only a URL that's recognised by chat, it can potentially one box it (ie - display a gist preview/the summary of a SO Q or A/a twitter post/an image etc...)... If you put other text on the line, it remains a link instead

Comment: I still think it would be helpful to opt-out of these things, per room per one-box.  Not sure if I should edit my post to be more general now..?

Comment: There's more pressing issues with the chat system than customising one-boxing per room - so... if this *ever* (and I'll be honest and say I highly doubt it) did happen it certainly wouldn't be this year, or most likely not even next. Your best bet is to educate users that you'd rather they don't one-box certain things if they're too long - and if they do - move it to the bin.

Comment: "There's more pressing issues with the chat system than customising one-boxing per room" like making other stuff onebox, for example cc @jon

Comment: I would like to see an option to turn off one boxing in a room completely.

Comment: @NathanOliver I like that idea. Do you think I should update my post to request opt-out of _all_ one-box features? I think it is a remedy for the time being.

Comment: @JonClements You may know this since you are a mod. Was gist oneboxing always a thing, that was broken until recently? Or is it, in fact, a new feature released recently?

Comment: @HunterStevens it's not a new feature - I'm fairly sure I've posted a gist that was one-boxed in 2013

Comment: Is older than that, from circa '10 http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/57288/revisions

Comment: @JonClements then I guess it was broken until recently. I know in the Ruby room, we have been posting gists, and today was the first I've seen it one-boxed.

Comment: @Braiam thanks... I figured it must have been around a while - was just stating when I believe I first used it. IIRC though - there might have been some issue with the URL format for gists changing and maybe only those in a certain format do get one-boxed?

Comment: @JonClements should I edit this to ask for "opt-out of all oneboxing"? Or is there already a meta post for that?

Comment: @HunterStevens don't recall seeing one specifically for that - but you might want to check MSE just in case

Comment: @JonClements from a brief search, it looks like the only recent MSE posts are for adding sites to the onebox feature. Should I ask for the opt-out here, or on MSE?

Comment: Shouldn't really matter. chat.SO happens to be on its own server so it might be that feature requests regarding it are best on MSO as they may not apply to the MSE server. The post can always be migrated if necessary anyway.

Comment: [*Similarly, please refrain from using oneboxes and other noisy formatting. (When posting a URL, put some text in front of it.)*](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation)

Comment: Here is a response from [ChrisJester-Young](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4325737#4325737) on the *bug* which happens to be an API limit issue.